# Results on the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Are there any papers that are significant to the proof of the RH? Are there also any common methods used to prove it? Were there any fundamental papers, or known results regarding this hypothesis? Work being done on it?

I am curious to see how other people would attack such a question, so that maybe I could understand higher level concepts more easily. And it is interesting.

Comment: Best of luck with your research. If you're really interested maybe start with Riemann's Zeta Function by Harold Edwards. Be sure to post your proof here!

Comment: @A rural reader I promise. See you in 10 years with the proof! I will link it from arxiv!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there is certainly a lot of work (to put it mildly) *around* it, I don't think anyone really has a good idea for a line of attack. There are various ideas about what such a line might look like broadly - see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69389/riemann-hypothesis-via-absolute-geometry) for one of them (with the caveat that "field with one element" is **not** what one might expect) - but no actual concrete approach is known, to the best of my knowledge.

Moreover there are known obstacles to resolving RH in either direction, most strikingly "near analogies" which are known to be true or known to be false. Such near analogues provide important negative information in that they demonstrate that certain approaches can't possibly work. So, for example, [we can immediately discard any claimed proof of RH which only uses the Euler product, meromorphic continuation, and functional equation](https://mathoverflow.net/a/283207/8133).